# Context in jQuery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have this jQuery function for chained drop down boxes:

```
  function updateCargoDestinations() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/truckingmanagement/account/getAccountUserCargoDestinations",
      data: "id=" + this.value,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#cargoDestination").html(html);
      }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {$("#account").change(updateCargoDestinations);});
```

It works great, but I also need the function to run one time when the page loads so the chained drop down box will populate correctly.  I have tried to set the context in the function like this:

`context: ("#account")`

but that is not working.  How can I make it so this function runs one time when the page loads AND runs when the observed drop down box is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `this.value` in a variable then check for `undefined`. If `undefined` set to whatever value it needs to initially populate the dropdown.

```
function updateCargoDestinations() {
    var selectId = this.value;
    if (typeof selectId === "undefined") {
         selectId = "whatever_you_need_here"; 
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: "/truckingmanagement/account/getAccountUserCargoDestinations",
      data: "id=" + selectId,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#cargoDestination").html(html);
      }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    updateCargoDestinations();
    $("#account").change(updateCargoDestinations);
});
```

Fiddle for undefined check: http://jsfiddle.net/kfJvA/1/

Comment: I guess I am having problems with `"whatever_you_need_here"`.  I would think I need the `id` of an element there, so I use `selectId = $("#account");` but that does not work for some reason.  Isn't this what the `context` attribute of the jQuery ajax function is supposed to take care of?

Comment: @typoknig `$("#account")` is the element itself, not the id. `selectId = "account"` is what should work but I completely guessing because I don't know what value you need there. Put whatever id you need as a default value to initially load the dropdown.

Comment: Figured it out (new to jQuery).  The trick was `selectId = $("#account").val();`.  Maybe add that into your answer to help someone else :)  Thanks!